# What's the workflow behind [user:display-name] token?

Tags: 8, users, tokens

I have seen in an email template, a token named **[user:display-name]**. Further noted that this token is not global, its value will only get rendered in email templates (correct me if I'm wrong).

How these specific tokens specially designed for only email tokens have been created?

In which file its logic is been written, I'm so curious, as the current user does not store any value of email receiver to whom email has to be sent. Then from where it picks the value of display name when current user is sending mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Clive said, the tokens are generated from [`hook_token_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/8.6.x) and [`hook_tokens()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens/8.6.x). For the `User` entity, those hooks are implemented from the *User* module. Token values aren't available just for email templates, but for every function/method that uses the [*token*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/token/8.6.x) service. For example, in a controller, I could use code similar to the following one.

```
$bubbleable_metadata = new BubbleableMetadata();
$build['#markup'] = $this->tokenService->replace('Tokens: [node:nid] [current-user:uid]', ['node' => $node], [], $bubbleable_metadata);
$bubbleable_metadata->applyTo($build);
```

As for getting the display name of a user account, that is easy: When user tokens are generated, `user_tokens()` gets a user object; calling [`User::getDisplayName()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetDisplayName/8.6.x) on that user object returns its display name.
See the code used from [`user_tokens()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.tokens.inc/function/user_tokens/8.6.x); in particular, see the following code. (Comments are mine.)

```
// Retrieves the user object passed to the hook.
$account = $data['user'];
```

```
// Generates the value for the display name token.
$replacements[$original] = $account
  ->getDisplayName();
if ($account->isAnonymous()) {
  $bubbleable_metadata->addCacheableDependency(\Drupal::config('user.settings'));
}
```

It is true there are user tokens available only for email templates, but that are generated from a callback used when replacing tokens in email templates. See [`user_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_mail/8.6.x) and [`user_mail_tokens()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_mail_tokens/8.6.x).

```
  // user_mail()
  $token_service = \Drupal::token();
  $language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager();
  $langcode = $message['langcode'];
  $variables = ['user' => $params['account']];
  $language = $language_manager->getLanguage($params['account']
    ->getPreferredLangcode());
  $original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);
  $mail_config = \Drupal::config('user.mail');
  $token_options = [
    'langcode' => $langcode,
    'callback' => 'user_mail_tokens',
    'clear' => TRUE,
  ];
  $message['subject'] .= PlainTextOutput::renderFromHtml($token_service
->replace($mail_config->get($key . '.subject'), $variables, $token_options));
  $message['body'][] = $token_service
    ->replace($mail_config->get($key . '.body'), $variables, $token_options);
```

```
function user_mail_tokens(&$replacements, $data, $options) {
  if (isset($data['user'])) {
    $replacements['[user:one-time-login-url]'] = user_pass_reset_url($data['user'], $options);
    $replacements['[user:cancel-url]'] = user_cancel_url($data['user'], $options);
  }
}
```

`user_mail()` says to [`Token::replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21Token.php/function/Token%3A%3Areplace/8.6.x) that `user_mail_tokens()` must be called after all the tokens are generated, and `user_mail_tokens()` replaces *[user:one-time-login-url]* and *[user:one-time-cancel-url]* (not replaced from `Token::replace()`) with the right values.

Similar code can be used from any module to generate tokens that must be  available only in specific context.

Answer (score 1):

> its value will only get rendered in email templates

Not true, that token is available any time the system gathers token for the user entity type.

> How these specific tokens specially designed for only email tokens have been created?

As mentioned they're not just for emails, but they're defined in [`user_token_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/8.5.x), and generated in [`user_tokens()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.tokens.inc/function/user_tokens/8.5.x).

> Then from where it picks the value of display name when current user is sending mail.

The token hook has access to the user account, so it simply uses `$account->getDisplayName();` to populate the data.